# How to make the sizes of every item in a RecyclerView different?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to achieve something like this:
[image: Google Keep]

But here's what I get after trying:
[image: My outcome]

I already set the height of the layout of the items to WRAP_CONTENT but the result is still the same.

What should I do?

Comment: It depends on your layoutmanager a lot. What are you using?

Comment: Layout is set using LayoutManager. Post your code to show what you are already doing

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam I use GridLayoutManager

Comment: in place of setting layout height use wrap_content

Comment: So please try to use the StaggeredLayoutManager. (Vertical) Grid layout suppose that children on the same row have the same height I guess.

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam Worked great. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! Happy coding!

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam I suggest you make this an answer instead of a comment

Comment: @MarkPazon Thanks. Yes it would be helpful for others who looking for this answer. I will take care next time.

Comment: Can someone tell me if I should use the same if I want all the items to be placed one below the other (list) and not in a grid, but also have different height (same as here, depending of the content by using WRAP_CONTENT) ?

Comment: I should only set the first argument to 1 (number of columns for vertical orientation), I looked it up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For those who are looking for an answer, just use a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` as the `RecyclerView`'s layout manager like this:

```
recycler.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```