# How to make a collection of images with in a view in android studio using Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

How to make a collection of images within a view in android studio using Recyclerview (Or any other suggestion)

Refer here for a detailed explanation. [How to make a collection of images with in a view in android studio using staggered layout (Or any other suggestion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64607773/how-to-make-a-collection-of-images-with-in-a-view-in-android-studio-using-stagge)

Nothing worked

Note: The question which previously asked has not worked as expected. Need a better solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a collection of images with in a view in android studio using staggered layout (Or any other suggestion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64607773/how-to-make-a-collection-of-images-with-in-a-view-in-android-studio-using-stagge)

Comment: That question not provided a correct solution for me